# Do 'undelete' votes expire?

Tags: discussion

Do undelete votes ever expire / is there some other mechanism that can cancel out undelete votes?

The reason I ask is because I came across [this deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof), which was deleted by 10 people on Nov 2, 2013, and now has 6 undelete votes on it ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9xPG.jpg) courtesy of Doorknob, who does not know I'm using it).

I can't really imagine why this question should be undeleted, and so it seems like what is happening is that over the past 5 months, about 1 person per month has voted to undelete. Eventually, over time, I suppose it will reach its threshold and be undeleted. Is that what is happening (i.e. do the votes not decay)?

If that is what is happening, does it make sense to undelete a question like this? I could imagine that, given sufficient time the undelete threshold on almost *any* question will eventually be reached, but this doesn't really seem like the way the system was intended to work -- there's no way for the community to voice *against* undeleting (or is there?).

Perhaps there should be a way to say "do *not* undelete", and have enough of those cancel out undelete votes?

Comment: No, delete and undelete votes do not ever expire. They're also not limited like close votes - you can vote to delete a post *again* once it's been undeleted.

Comment: @animuson So I should keep an eye on questions like this, then vote to delete it if it ever becomes undeleted? And then if it does get deleted, it goes back to being undeleted over time, then repeat, forever?

Comment: How dare you steal my screenshot?! :-P

Comment: Why would anyone vote to undelete a question like that? It's clearly an open-ended tool recommendation, which is totally not appropriate according to [SO's current guidelines for appropriate questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Seems like a big waste of time for people to undelete it, just to have other people go and delete it ***again*** :P (smh)

Comment: @Cupcake If we really want to - yes. We can lock it, which would prevent further undelete votes and thus prevent undeletion.

Comment: @animuson Though the lock would be unnecessary if a mod just deleted the post, since then it wouldn't be undeletable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, delete and undelete votes never expire. This makes sense, in my opinion, and I don't think they need to expire.

In the beginning posts could be deleted and undeleted endlessly, even by the same users each time, and the only way to stop the loop was for moderator to come over and lock the post, forcing him to leave it undeleted because three high rep users could override moderator deletion.

This was changed [exactly three years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77107/lock-posts-by-default-when-deleted-by-a-moderator) per request, and since then ordinary diamondless users can't undelete a post deleted by a moderator.

This nullifies the "Perhaps there should be a way to say do not undelete", as in cases it's needed a moderator can step in, undelete then delete using the diamond power and it can't be undeleted anymore.

Comment: Thanks; the moderator lock is the point I was missing. That would be able to solve any potential issues.